# Regex to extract UK Currency including £ symbol and Pence (p)

Tags: regex, currency

I am fairly new to RegEx and have had a search around online but am unable to find a regex that fits my requirements.

The ultimate aim is to search a string of text and extract the lowest monetary amount, however as the string may contain more than one £amount, then i'm happy for a regex to just extract all monetary values it can find and then I can write a calculation in order to return the lowest amount.

The string may have numbers that are not monetary values / numerous amounts, therefore the regex should always look for a £ symbol first OR it could end with a "p" or "P" to signify pence. For example "I need 2 of these at £10 each and one of those at 50p" - should return 10.00 & 0.50 - I can then calculate that 0.50 is the lowest amount.

As people also write their amounts in various ways, I need the regex to be able to spot different patterns - including the "," for every thousand. All below values should be valid:

£0 
£0.00 
£0.00p 
£0000 
£0000.00 
£0000.00p 
£0,000 
£0,000.00 
£0,000.00p 
0p

Hopefully someone may be able to advise the best way to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: I always find https://rubular.com/ helpful

Comment: I think the reason your question is getting voted down is the lack of programming on your side. The SO idea is that when you get stuck on a task, you show what you've tried so far. Here, you've just given a spec and asked someone else to program.

Comment: ok, I understand, i've known about regex for a while, but only looked into using it yesterday so it seems quite baffling to me, I managed to work out a very basic regex that detected a £ symbol and then the following numeric digits: .£\d+ however, i've no idea how you can put optional / and's / or's in there, appreciate you have to take time to learn this, but i'm on a quick turn around and at this moment in time, can't invest too much time trying to work out how to perform my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on your data set:

```
(?=^£|.*p$)£?\d*(?:,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?p?
```

But it may improperly match some edge cases as well because everything is optional...

https://regex101.com/r/WptUn6/3

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus this seems to work, however I tweaked it slightly '(?=^£|.*p$)£?\d*(?:,\d{3})*(\.[0-9])?p?' so that any pence value will be caught, not just 0s. Thanks again, I would never have been able to come up with this with my limited knowledge of regex!

Comment: @pezz You're welcome. See my updated regex because you should use `\d+` to capture any pence value because `[0-9]` will just capture one digit after the decimal point

Comment: I tweaked it again to allow more than one digit after the decimal point `(?=^£|.*p$)£?\d*(?:,\d{3})*(\.[0-9]\d)?p?` Thanks again

Comment: @pezz That works but you can do `\.\d{2}` if you expect to only encounter exactly 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: thanks for your help yesterday, I have been testing it out on this string: I need to find this amount: £100.00 and also this £123,123.12 and also this £44.99 and this £0.44 and this 40p and £0.44p." yet the regex doesn't find the 40p. If i remove the decimal point at the end of the sentence, then the regex does find it, but it also finds lots of white space too.  I also removed the ^ from the £ so it looks within the whole text and not the opening characters of the sentence. `(?=£|.*p$)£?\d*(?:,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?p?`

Comment: As an alternative solution, could i create 2 separate regex, one that looks for £s (e.g. £100, £100.50, £100.40p) and one that looks for pence only (e,g, 50p, 40p). I can then run the the string through both regex and compare all results to determine the lowest value. Thanks

Comment: @pezz The regex works for all of those things you just commented, see https://regex101.com/r/WptUn6/4. If you are trying to extract currency from a long piece of arbitrary text then you should provide an example of such text in your question. My assumption was that you're just checking individual pieces of text and testing whether it is or is not a currency.